# How can I backup remotely the entire Linux server using rsync over SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, backup, centos, rsync

I own a CentOS 6.9 box

I need to backup remotely my entire CentOS installation to my Rsync.net storage account through SSH.

How would that be possible including incremental updates and excluding system directories (like lost+found) that are useless for future transfer to other box ?

Comment: *Excluding* `/home`? That's a little...

Comment: Different parts of your system need different backup proceedures.  For example, after initial configuration, `/etc` and subdirs and content rarely change.  Your data files (users homes, maildirs, etc) change constantly.  I'd split your backup process into multiples and use appropriate for each...

Comment: I agree but this does not answer the question, even partially on how to do it using rsync over ssh with exclusions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can backup my Linux installation with exclusions using `rsync` command to my remote Rsync.net account or to any remote storage account through SSH with the following command

> `rsync -avzh --progress --delete --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/home/*,/lost+found,/backup/*} -e ssh /var username@myhost.rsync.net:remote_folder`

Backups are incremental by default.

Parameters explained:

> -a: archive mode (it keeps ownership, timestamp, permissions)
>
> -v: verbose
>
> -z: compress file data
>
> -h: human-readable format
>
> --delete: updates remote if files have been deleted from local
>
> --progress: shows progress

[rsync man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Comment: So, if I understand it correctly, you are missing the incremental part... that's why I'm suggesting you `rsnapshot`.

Comment: `rsync` does incremental backup by default, so no, I would not miss it :) .. anyway your answer was only a suggestion for something different instead of an answer to my question.

Comment: So in this example, you are backing up the local `/var` folder to the remote? If so, then why all the excludes for other folders that aren't being copied? What does `-e` do?

Comment: @Cadmos: by "incremental backup" he means a backup that keeps some "history" or "versioning", where you can restore a file as it was in a given point in the past, not just the most recent version. In this sense `rsync` is a _mirror_ backup.